# How to update record mysql using javascript or something similar

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Is there an easy way to update this query using javascript or something similar ? I am using a simple cache that isn't updating this query:

```
$query_rs_update = sprintf("UPDATE cute_news SET views = views+1 WHERE id = %s", GetSQLValueString($colname_DetailRS1, "int"));
$rs_update = mysql_query($query_rs_update) or die(mysql_error());
```

Trying to get it to record views, even when the cache is on ?

Thanks NINJAS!!!

Comment: You could use AJAX. But, not sure if I get what you mean by... emm.. still don't get.

Comment: All I am doing is updating a record in a MYSQL table ?

Answer (score 2):

Typically, Javascript does not interact directly with a database. The good thing about this is that a hacker can't abuse your system by exploiting publicly visible code.

What you'll want to do is create a script that can be called from javascript using AJAX (POST) and that will perform any logic you need. In your case, it looks like your AJAX call will pass along a news article id.

Also, I recommend using prepared statements or another protected query technique so that your code isn't SQL injectable (like PDO prepared statements).

Comment: Interesting information! THanks! Any chance you could help with the code like I asked ?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Uh2YBhLH Here's some Javascript for using jQuery post. I included links to php PDO because that's already well-documented. jQuery is also well documented at the link I gave.